# Exploring the Galapagos Islands with a Disabled Individual

Tags: accessibility, galapagos-islands

I'm trying to figure out the best way to explore the Galapagos Islands for someone that is disabled. The disability is with walking, but not wheelchair-bound. I'm aware of how to get to the islands, but I'm not sure what type of tour (or no tour) would be best in terms of -

- Accessibility
- Pace
- Experience

I'm not sure how accessible the islands are on a whole, or which locations would be best to visit to ensure accessibility. I'm also not sure about what mode of travel would be best to ensure a good experience and manageable pace.

Comment: @pnuts yeah, I might have chosen the wrong word. I was more meaning the amount of time for each activity in terms of planned itinerary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to go anywhere beyond what you can drive to, you need to join a tour or hire your own personal naturalist/guide.  That's what my Galapagos guide said anyway.

The crew on our ship were pretty good at helping folks in and out of the zodiac boats, but you'll want to evaluate whether this person will find getting in and out of boats too taxing.  Some of the walks on the smaller islands are short and have little elevation (Darwin's Steps excepted), but the footing is rarely smooth unless you're walking a beach.  Our guide did not allow the group to be split up.  Letting group members stray seems to be officially discouraged.

I've heard of at least one tour that gets around the Galapagos by flying.  I think that was designed for people who suffer from sea-sickness or who just don't want to sleep on a boat. A disabled person might find this option helpful.